# Why was Electro summoned by Dr. Strange's spell?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, Doctor Strange explains that his spell, which was supposed to make everyone in the world forget that Peter Parker is Spider-Man, has instead summoned people from other worlds who already know Peter Parker is Spider-Man.

This explains the arrival of Doc Ock, the Goblin, Sandman and the Lizard, all of whom learned Peter was Spider-Man in their original appearances – but it does not account for Electro's presence.

Electro never learned Spider-Man's true identity in *The Amazing Spider-Man 2* and so should not have been affected by Doctor Strange's spell. (I also realised that it is explicitly said during the final fight that Electro did not know who Spider-Man was: *"I just thought you were gonna be Black."*)

Why was Electro summoned by Dr. Strange's spell?

Comment: Possibly he's an Electro-*variant*

Comment: The key point is that the spell was said have summoned people from other realities who _knew that Peter Parker was Spider-Man_. This version of Electro -- whether a variant or not -- said he thought Spidey was a black guy under the mask, which strongly suggests he didn't know Spidey's actual secret ID. Eddie Brock's presence in the MCU is a mystery for the same reason, although his initial transportation between realities coincided with the symbiote revealing some unspecified info to him.

Comment: http://images5.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED14/510839c1ea467.jpeg

Comment: Possibly Electro isn’t an Electro-variant (or still can be), but his black Spider-man whom he knows the secret identify of is.

Comment: Max's dialogue suggests he didn't know the identity or race of his Spider-Man. He just _assumed_ Spidey was black, because he was from Queens and helped "poor people".

Comment: It's probably easier to assume Dr. Strange was incorrect and doesn't know what he did. In fact the trailer puts the emphasis on their common link really being died in battle (which if that too is incorrect I didn't see some of those).  Anyway our Peter caused a Rick and Morty level of unintended destruction it's shocking to me Peter isn't depressed.  I was expecting a twist ending where it was like "It's a Wonderful  Life" and Peter realizes he has it good and Strange gets him a consequence free lesson.  As far as epic mistakes go MCU spiderman has to have made the worst one in the multiverse.

Comment: _"In fact the trailer puts the emphasis on their common link really being died in battle (which if that too is incorrect I didn't see some of those)."_ Sandman and Lizard didn't die in their previous outings, so that theory doesn't fit. (Ock died, but not strictly _in battle_ either.) Also, Strange fixed the problem by making everyone forget who Peter was, which fits with _his_ explanation.

Comment: Related: [In Spider-Man No Way Home, how did *this villain* come into this universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/116482/49)

Answer (score 21):

When Electro is describing his final battle with Spider-Man, he says that he became a being of pure energy, and was in "the grid" absorbing both power and information (from the internet, I guess?)

Presumably some of the information he absorbed included Spider-Man’s real name, though clearly not his appearance.

Comment: This is a very plausible explanation! I like it.

Comment: @Roberto yeah it might be the best we can do based on the film itself.

Comment: While this seems plausible...it is contradicted by Electro's statement during the final fight 
(I just thought you were gonna be Black).

Comment: @user96551 You might want to read the last sentence of my answer, rather than just the first.

Comment: Not a lot of evidence one way or the other but this *does* fit...

Answer (score 15):

There's a throwaway line in the film about him "absorbing data". Presumably that data included Spider-Man's secret identity.

> "I was whoopin' Spider-Man's ass, he'll tell you! And then, he caused
> an overload. **I was stuck in the grid, absorbing data.** I was about to
> turn into pure energy, and then... oh shit. I was about to die."

That being said, assuming this Electro is the same Electro from The Amazing Spider-Man 2, he might have overheard Gwen say Peter's name during their battle.

This would also explain why he didn't know that "Peter" was a white dude if all he knew was his name.