# Are any of these characters from the end of Spider-Man: No Way Home identifiable?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, spider-man-no-way-home

Near the end of *No Way Home*,

> multiple silhouettes are seen encroaching into the main universe from alternate ones.

Are these identifiable characters? The one holding some sort of spear seems like it could be someone specific.

Comment: My guess is that those guys aren't related to Spider-Man but to the next Dr. Strange film. They could all be inter-dimensional monsters that [spoiler ahead] we see in the second post credits scene

Comment: @Shreedar Doctor Strange explicitly says in the movie that the spell is trying to pull everyone from the multiverse who knows Spider-Man’s identity into their universe. He could be wrong, but I’m not sure what purpose that twist would serve in later movies.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yes you're right. But Electro came through and so did Eddie (who both did not know about Peter's secret identity). Anyways, its just been  a week since the release so I guess new information will be out soon.

Comment: @Shreedhar although [both Electro](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258354/why-was-electro-summoned-by-dr-stranges-spell) and [the symbiote](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258446/why-is-this-character-transported-into-the-mcu) have lines vaguely alluding to methods by which they could have learned it, which don’t have any other obvious purpose in the script.

Comment: There are also *infinite* universes, therefore infinite people who know Peter Parker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ComicBook.com](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/spider-man-no-way-home-teases-more-villains-from-multiverse/) and other sources claim we can see

> Kraven, the Scorpion, Rhino and Black Cat

No picture (obviously) and no Word of God to back their claim though.

---

Edit: now that the movie has been released in Blue Ray, [IGN identified the characters](https://www.ign.com/articles/7-spider-man-villain-silhouettes-identified-from-no-way-home-finale)

> Kraven the Hunter, Doppelganger or Superior Spiderman (Otto Octavius), Scorpio, Black Cat, Rhino, Mysterio (or Miles Morales?), and Madame Web.

Some of the characters appeared in the MCU (numbers 3,5,6), while movies about others (1,4) are in development.

Comment: The identity of the characters is not obvious to me from the pictures in the IGN article. I guess it is easier from the video itself. I don't have the Blue Ray, so I can't check it. I may try to add pictures if a high-resolution video pops up on Youtube or another platform. Since the article tries to guess the identity of the characters from the video, I guess the audio commentary does not give this information.

Answer (score 8):

One of them I recognized was definitely Rhino. The spear silhouette that was most prominent could possibly be Kraven. So I assume they are Spidey-related characters from other universes that know his identity, not some unrelated interdimensional beings.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard speculation from friends and on podcasts that the figure with the spear is Kraven the Hunter, who has [his own Sony movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraven_the_Hunter#Sony.27s_Spider-Man_Universe) scheduled for release in January 2023.

[image]

We may have to wait for screen grabs to start tracing the other  outlines onto old comic books.

Comment: there are several, and they don't look like humans. Kraven is not an extra dimensional being

Comment: @Noweh “there are several” — there’s probably about 100. Do I have to guess all of them? “they don't look like humans” —  I’m not clear what precludes the indistinct hazy blobs from being representations of humans. “Kraven is not an extra dimensional being” — neither’s the Lizard, or any of the other heroes and villains in the movie, until the events of the movie pull them into the MCU. The entire premise of the climax is that an infinite number of beings from across the multiverse, like the ones we’ve already seen in the movie, are being pulled into the MCU by spell.

Answer (score -3):

> One of the shades appears to be the Celestial we saw in the Flashback with the Collektor in Guardens of the Galaxy 1. Where he shows the history of the power stone where the planet is destroyed.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the visual similarities between the shape in the dimensional breach and the character you mentioned?

Comment: I think the Celestial in the flashback in _Guardians_ looks a lot like Arishem from _Eternals_. Maybe Cersi figured out who Spider-Man was!